# Display parcel by number entered into QLineEdit

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I created a custom search form. Once displayed in QGIS, if I enter a record number into `QLineEdit` and hit OK button, I want to display and zoom corresponding parcel.

Here is my code :

```py
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import*
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas
import qgis.utils 
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui 
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QWidget


def my_form_open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    control = dialog.findChild(QWidget, "MyLineEdit")

self.connect(self.ui.buttonbox,SIGNAL("clicked()"),self.cherche_NDossier)

def cherche_NDossier(self):
    NDossier = self.ui.QLineEdit.text()
    feature = layer.getFeatures().next()
    NDossier_trouve = selection.cherche_NDossier()
    self.affiche_resultat_et_zoom(NDossier_trouve)
```

A screenshot of my form :

[image: my form]

Comment: Please consider using a web translator to post your question in English, thank you.

Comment: Do you have to develop under QGIS 2 ? QGIS 2 is no longer maintained.

Comment: La version de QGIS? QGIS 2 ou QGIS 3?

Comment: i use QGIS 2.18